# Tastypie requests showing Anonymous user even after Logging In

Tags: django, angularjs, tastypie

I am working on a project in angularjs and django 1.6

```
        login(request, user)
        print(request.user, request.user.id)
```

The login is done using standard login from django.contrib.auth in the LoginResource. Inside that it successfully prints user and its id.

Then after logging in i tried another api request from client side.Say there is a MessageResource model. And it has archive function.

```
def archive(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
    data = self.deserialize(request, request.body,format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
    arch_data = data.get('arch_list', '')
    print(request.user, request.user.id)
```

So i tried to track the user inside this function.But
the last print line prints

```
AnonymousUser None
```

Means the user data is not stored in it. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong ? How can i get the login user from request?

Answer (score 3):

## Cause one - authentication that doesn't attach user to request

It depends of authorization in particular resource.

Let say if you are using `ApiKeyAuthorization` the user is fetched from credentials and assigned to the request during execution of authentication's `is_authenticated` method here: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py#L206

But if you are using standard `Authentication`, the method `is_authenticated` doesn't check or assign anything: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py#L47. So event if there are credentials in request they wont be checked or assigned.

## Cause two - using resource extended methods doesn't provide authentication etc.

Yes in this case you have to check on your own: allowed http methods authorization, authentication, serialize request.body etc.

If your `authentication` assign user to request in `is_authenticated` method like `ApiKeyAuthentication` does for instance. You just add one line:

```
def archive(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
    self.is_authenticated(request)
    data = self.deserialize(request, request.body,format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
    arch_data = data.get('arch_list', '')
    print(request.user, request.user.id)
```

Comment: I missied this: *self.is_authenticated(request)* Thank you very much